# Блокировка клавиши на клавиатуре Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windowsphone

Для ввода текста в элемент `TextBox` в разметке страницы использую клавиатуру`Number`. Но там присутствует символ "запятая". Можно ли как-нибудь ограничить его нажатие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно подписаться на нажатие клавиши и отсекать ненужные символы. Правда выглядеть это будет не очень красиво с т.з. UX, поскольку в идеале запрещенная клавиша либо должна отсутствовать, либо должна быть недоступна для нажатия. Да и код выглядит тоже нее идеально из-за куцего API.

```
private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (textBox.Text.Contains(','))
    {
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace(",", "");
        textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
    }
}
```